# cancan and views testing with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, capybara, cancan

sorry for my english, I have a problem while testing views with capybara. Capybara can't view the elements validated with cancan, I have this in my tests, to simulate that the user has permissions for all.

```
before(:each) do
  permission = FactoryGirl.create(:permission)
  role = FactoryGirl.build(:role)
  role.permissions << permission
  role.save
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :role_id => role.id)
  sign_in user
end
```

and this in my views...

```
= link_to t('actions.new'), new_user_path if can?(:create, User)
```

But my tests don't pass

```
 Failure/Error: click_link t('actions.new')
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   no link with title, id or text 'Crear nuev@' found
 # (eval):2:in `click_link'
 # ./spec/views/users_spec.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I don't understand, my controllers hasn't problems.

Some help?

Thanks in advance, Regards...

Comment: don't use link texts, use ids!

Comment: I used ids but doesn't work :/ I have noted that is not necesary assign permissions to current_user to test controllers, is as having permissions for everything, although not are specified (my controllers has restrictions, of course)

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried using capybara with internationalization but I can imagine you might run into some issues.

I'd follow @phoet's advice and use an ID in your link instead of the translated link text. Capybara's `click_link` will look for either an ID or link text.

```
# add ID to link in view
= link_to(t('actions.new'), new_user_path, :id => 'actions_new') if can?(:create, User)
```

.

```
# in test file
click_link 'actions_new'
```